# Ag-Grid: Show options depending the choice on another field

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm building a new grid but i need a select field that options appear depending on the choice of the first field.

I have two cellEditors

```
  columnDefs = [

{ field: 'typePizza', editable:true, cellEditor:'pizza'},
{ field: 'toppings', editable: true, cellEditor: 'gridSelect' }
```

];

The 'pizza' one is a select that i choose a type of pizza, the gridSelect have a multiple select that i can choose one or more ingredients but I need to show the options that are affected by the type of pizza.

I have this toppingList on gridSelectComponent:  `toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];`

And PizzaList on PizzaComponent `pizzaList: string[] = ['Pizza A','Pizza B', 'Pizza C'];`

For example, if i choose **Pizza A** i want that on that row only appear the options '**Extra Cheese, Onion**' options.

If i choose **Pizza B** only appear the options '**Mushroom, Tomato**'

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cccf3b?file=src/styles.css)

How can i do this?

Thank you

Comment: You need to post your full code or create a Plunker.

Comment: @ViqMontana i have added the stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `mat-select`, upon the event of the dropdown being expanded, call a method in your class:

```
(openedChange)="matOpenedChanged($event)"
```

In this method, see what the value of the `typePizza` field is and set your dropdown list appropriately:

```
matOpenedChanged(event) {
    const currentPizzaType = this.params.data.typePizza;
    if (currentPizzaType == 'Pizza A') {
      this.toppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Onion'];
    } else if (currentPizzaType == 'Pizza B') {
      this.toppingList = ['Mushroom', 'Tomato'];
    } else {
      this.toppingList = [
        'Extra cheese',
        'Mushroom',
        'Onion',
        'Pepperoni',
        'Sausage',
        'Tomato'
      ];
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ddp12?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgridselect%2Fgridselect.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D To do this dynamically, what i need to do is create a method thats returns the values by an id, for example, right?